# Auto incrementing column including year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, auto-increment

I need to create a table with an ID column that increments automatically and concatenates the current year, for example:

`year = 2018 ==> 20181 , 20182 , 20183 , etc`
`year = 2020 ==> 20201 , 20202 , 20203 , etc`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a sequence :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_myTable START WITH 1;
```

and then use it in a trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_myTable 
BEFORE INSERT ON myTable 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_year varchar2(4):=to_char(sysdate,'yyyy');
BEGIN
 :new.id := v_year||seq_myTable.nextval;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The following requires Oracle 12.1 or later:

```
create sequence demo_seq;

create table demo
( genid   varchar2(10) default on null to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')||demo_seq.nextval
          constraint demo_pk primary key
, somecol varchar2(10) );

insert into demo (somecol) values ('Kittens');
insert into demo (somecol) values ('Puppies');

select * from demo;

GENID      SOMECOL
---------- ----------
20181      Kittens
20182      Puppies
```

The only limitation here is that the sequence doesn't restart for each year. To automate this, I think you would have to abandon the sequence and use a `select max +1` approach with some explicit serialisation (`dbms_lock` or similar). Alternatively, schedule a job to restart the sequence each year.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no such way to do this with automatic mechanisms as a generated Id.

I see a few options here:

- use 2 columns: Id and Year
- use a [virtual column](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/de/community/dbadmin/tipps/virtual_columns/index.html)
- use a function in a on insert trigger to build your custom id

I'd recommend using 2 columns and a primary key over the id column and a index over the year column as it's the most clean implementation i can think of (and perhaps the fastest as well).
+ you should use your id as id and another column to see which year it's been added, or even a date column if you need the information the record has been inserted